# AWS : Using Data Pipeline to convert CSV file to JSON file (stored on S3)

Tags: json, csv, amazon-web-services, converters, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a large CSV file which I want to convert into JSON such that every column in the CSV becomes a JSON entry.

Example:

```
dfef22s,John,30,0
```

Becomes:

```
{UUID: "dfef22s", name: "John", age: 30, isHappy: 0}
```

My files are stored on AWS S3 and I would like to perform this using 
AWS data pipeline (I'm aware there are online tools and libraries etc but I dont want to use them).

How can I do it using AWS data pipeline ?

Comment: Do you want the output to go to S3? Redshift?